# How will swagger work with spring boot if there is no rest controller, no request mapping annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

In my service there are only POJOs present but I don't need any controller to send them from any API, I just want to make a swagger documentation but they say there is no way to make swagger without the rest controller. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Generally swagger is used for documenting REST api but still you tweak it. Hope you are looking to generate schema/ dtos